# LINQ Additional Filter in Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, linq

I am unfamiliar with LINQ and I am trying to modify an existing query.

Below is the code snippet and the filter that I would like to add in:

```
ViewData["Employees"] = emps = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                from jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                                .Where(x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.jobinfo_id).Take(1)
                                select new { staff, jobinfo })

.Select(x => x.staff).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Alias).ToList();

*** Insert Additional filter at the .Select statement above 
<where (jobinfo.last_date == null)>
```

May I know how can it be done?

Comment: Did you try append the condition to existing WHERE clause?
Something like this ; `.Where(x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID && jobinfo.last_date == null)`?

Comment: @RasanjanaN yes I did try to insert a `where` clause in the statement. The statement you provided can be applied to the place where `select new { staff, jobinfo })` is. The last statement `.Select` seems to be working differently so I am unable to insert into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try like below and check in the third line?

```
.Where(x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID && x.last_date == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

two options one is to use && and use another where as follows

```
   ViewData["Employees"] = emps = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                from jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                                .Where((x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID) && (jobinfo.last_date == null))
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.jobinfo_id).Take(1)
                                select new { staff, jobinfo })

.Select(x => x.staff).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Alias).ToList();
```

Other options would be

```
 ViewData["Employees"] = emps = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                from jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                                .Where((x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID)).Where(jobinfo.last_date == null)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.jobinfo_id).Take(1)
                                select new { staff, jobinfo })

.Select(x => x.staff).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Alias).ToList();
```